# Show that $\text {ran} (T + K)$ is closed.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

> Let $\mathcal H$ be a Hilbert  space. Let $T \in \mathcal L(\mathcal H)$ and $K$ be a compact operator on $\mathcal H.$ If $\text {ran} (T)$ is a closed subspace of $\mathcal H$ then show that $\text {ran} (T+K)$ is also closed.

Let $\{(T + K)x_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence in $\text {ran} (T + K)$ converging to $x \in \mathcal H.$ If $\{x_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ is a bounded sequence then $\{Kx_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ will have a convergent subsequence say $\left \{Kx_{n_k}\right \}_{k \geq 1}$ converging to $y$ (say). Then $Tx_{n_k} \to (x - y).$ But since $\text {ran} (T)$ is closed it follows that there exists $z \in \mathcal H$ such that $(x - y) = Tz.$ So $x = y + Tz.$ Now I get stuck and couldn't proceed further. Because $y$ might not necessarily be in the range of $K.$ Instead what I can say is that there exists a closed ball $B$ of some positive radius such that $\overline {K(B)}$ contains $y.$ Also I have no idea how to proceed when $\{x_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ is unbounded. Some help is very much required at this moment.

Thanks for your time for reading.

Comment: what is $ran(T)$?

Comment: @Praphulla Koushik $\text {ran} (T)$ represents the range of the operator $T.$

Comment: Assuming $range(T)$ is a closed subset, I think that, if $(x_n)$ is unbounded, then, the sequence $(T+K)(x_n)$ does not even converge.. Have you tried in this direction?

Comment: @Praphulla Koushik Yes, I have tried but couldn't succeed. I don't get a proper argument here. May be there is some clever way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The result if FALSE.  For a counter-example, take $T$ to be the zero operator and $K$ any compact operator with a non-closed range.